# How to create custom filter option box in datatables, Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

how to create custom data filter in datatables ?,

If I select one of the lines in the option box:
[image]

then datatables will display the value of the option box in datatables:
[image]

this is an example that I want in my custom search:
[image]

finally my custom search succeeded
[image]

I show the data (Department) from the join with table dept in database

in my datatables i used table emp in database

this is my code option box

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form action="<?=site_url('proses/pindah_departemen');?>" method="get">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Filter Data</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Pilih Departemen</td>
                        <td width="30%">
                            <select class="form-control" name="filter_departemen">
                                <option value="" <?php if(empty($this->input->get('filter_departemen'))) echo 'selected';?>>Show All data</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach($groups as $city)
                                {
                                    $selected = $this->input->get('filter_departemen')==$city['dept_id_auto'] ? 'selected':'';
                                    echo '<option value="'.$city['dept_id_auto'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$city['dept_name'].'</option>';
                                }
                                ?> 
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tampilkan Data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is My Controller named(Proses) :

```
public function pindah_departemen()
{
    $data = array(
        'title'     => 'Pindah Departemen',
        'data' => $this->Pindah_dept_model->GetSiswa($this->input->get('filter_departemen'))
    );

    $data['groups'] = $this->Pindah_dept_model->getAllGroups();

    $this->template->load('template','proses/pindah_departemen', $data);
}
```

And This My Model Named (Pindah_dept_model) :

```
var $table = 'emp';

public function GetSiswa()
{
    /*i dont know exactly  your query. please fix this is this wrong*/
    $this->db->select(array('emp_id', 'first_name', 'nik', 'gender', 'pin', 'dept_name'))
        ->from('emp AS e')
        ->join('dept AS d','d.dept_id_auto = e.dept_id_auto', 'left');
    if(!empty($dep)) $this->db->where('d.dept_id_auto', $dep); 
    $data = $this->db->order_by('emp_id','ASC')->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}

public function getAllGroups()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT dept_id_auto,dept_name FROM dept');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: wew.. do you not use ajax? really?

Comment: how if i write new code, and you learn that from it? because its totally useless if i answer this question since you dont understand how to do this properly

Comment: ok that's a good idea bro, i'll wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your filter html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form action="<?=site_url('proses/pindah_departemen');?>" method="get">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Filter Data</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%">Pilih Departemen</td>
                            <td width="30%">
                                <select class="form-control" name="filter_departemen">
                                    <option value="" <?php if(empty($this->input->get('filter_departemen'))) echo 'selected';?>>Show All data</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($groups as $city)
                                    {
                                        $selected = $this->input->get('filter_departemen')==$city['dept_id_auto'] ? 'selected':'';
                                        echo '<option value="'.$city['dept_id_auto'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$city['dept_name'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?> 
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tampilkan Data</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

your controller

```
public function pindah_departemen()
{
    // MASUKKAN PARAMETER DATA DISINI, BIASANYA HASIL DARI QUERY
    $data = array(
            'title'     => 'Pindah Departemen',
            'data' => $this->Pindah_dept_model->GetSiswa($this->input->get('filter_departemen'))
        );
    $data['groups'] = $this->Pindah_dept_model->getAllGroups();
    $this->template->load('template','proses/pindah_departemen', $data);
}
```

your model

```
var $table = 'emp';

public function GetSiswa($dep=NULL)
{
    $this->db->select(array('emp_id', 'first_name', 'nik', 'gender', 'pin', 'dept_name')) //or select(array('emp_id, first_name, nik, gender, pin, dept_name')
        ->from('emp AS e')
        ->join('dept AS d','d.dept_id_auto = e.dept_id_auto', 'left');
    if(!empty($dep)) $this->db->where('dept_id_auto', $dep);
    $data = $this->db->order_by('emp_id','ASC')->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}

public function getAllGroups()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT dept_id_auto,dept_name FROM dept');
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_by_id_siswa($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('emp_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

advice: next time, plz learn jquery and ajax before build new apps again.

Comment: wew.. i just know if my question is totally same with `eiji`. only 5% is different. but it doesnt matter. If my answer solve your prob, just check Eiji answer (not mine)

Comment: this really totally useless to write this code. because you better solve this using ajax instead native. With ajax you can do like this: http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/table_datatables_ajax.html but sad, im so sleepy now to create ajax example. anyway if you need help, just join us in https://kask.us/ikiNI

Comment: please check my new post bro, it still error, thanks before

Comment: find this line and change with this: `if(!empty($dep)) $this->db->where('d.dept_id_auto', $dep);` ps: im using phone now. Cant edit well. I just add `d` in front of dept_id_auto

Comment: check my latest post, this will work only datatables can not display data from the database

Comment: lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163843/datatables-ci 15mins no response, i will go sleep

Comment: thanks nimbuzz, finally custom searchku successful, may I edit your post a little?, just add this `select(array('emp_id', 'first_name', 'nik', 'gender', 'pin', 'dept_name'))`

Comment: yup. sorry i miss that. i will accept the edit, and i left my code fix in the bottom of that

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood the problem, you want to add a filter on the "getAllGroup" function from the selectbox. Correct me if I'm wrong.

1. You should add a name to the select, I name it "dept_filter" for the rest.

   ```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
           <div class="panel-heading">Filter Data</div>
           <form action="" method="post">
           <div class="panel-body">
                     <table class="table table-bordered">
               <tr>
                 <td width="20%">Pilih Departemen</td>
                 <td width="30%">
                   <select class="form-control" name="dept_filter">
                     <?php
                       foreach($groups as $city)
                       {
                           echo '<option value="'.$city['dept_id_auto'].'">'.$city['dept_name'].'</option>';
                       }
                     ?> 
                   </select>
                 </td>
               </tr>
             </table>          
           </div>
           <div class="panel-footer text-right">
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Tampilkan Data">
           </div>
           </form>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   ```
2. In your Proses controller :

   ```
   public function pindah_departemen()
   {

       //we take the current selected option (return false when none)
       $filter_dept = $this->input->post('dept_filter');

       //and we pass it to the model
       $data = array(
           'title'     => 'Pindah Departemen',
           'data' => $this->Pindah_dept_model->GetSiswa($filter_dept)
       );
       $data['groups'] = $this->Pindah_dept_model->getAllGroups();

       $this->template->load('template','proses/pindah_departemen', $data);
   }
   ```
3. In your model : I have convert your sql query in codeigniter query builder syntaxe.

   ```
       /*to avoid any conflict if this function is used anywhere else, 
       I made the param optionnal, so if there is none, 
       the filter is set to "false"*/
       public function GetSiswa($filter = FALSE)
       {

           $this->db->select();
           $this->db->from($this->table); //here "emp"
           //do the same join as your query
           $this->db->join('dept', 'debt.dept_id_auto = emp.dept_id_auto'); 

           //when the filter isn't false, we add a "where" condition
           if($filter){
               $this->db->where("dept_id_auto", $filter);
           }

           $this->db->order_by("emp_id", "DESC");

           $query = $this->db->get();

           return $data->result_array();
       }
   ```

---

**Udpate :** Code updated to the current problem.

**Udpate2 :** Change "dept_name" for "dept_id_auto" in the SQL where condition

### **Update 3: ** Fix the HTML by adding the form tag

If you don't have the good result :

1. do you have your `<select>...</select>` in a `<form>`?
2. Are you using `method="post"` in your `<form>`?
3. Can you check if you receive the post data in your controller with a 
       `var_dump($this->input->post());`
4. Can you check the current query run in your GetSiswa() function by adding the row 
       `echo $this->db->last_query();`
   just before the return?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what I mean is,
if you select one of the lines in the dropdown and you click on the "Show Data" button, datatables will reload and display the data you want. For example if you select "STAFF" in the dropdown column then datatables will reload and will display the data with value "STAFF" in coloumn Department

Comment: I have edited my post please see again and please help me to fix my codes

Comment: Give me your Database strucure of the table "emp" please

Comment: I have edited my post please look again and please help me

Comment: Ok, so.
You have to filter your list "employe" by their "dept_id". So the main work is to do in GetSiswa, where we have to add a filter to your current request.
I'm working on it.

Comment: i mean just like this, 
http://livedemo.mbahcoding.com/serverside_datatables_custom_filter/
I have tried it but failed, if you look at the website, I want to create like a country dropdown where if you choose one from the list, and pressed the filter, datatables will reload and display the data you selected in the previous dropdown

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Why it doesn't work? Something is wrong?

Comment: I have edit my post, please look at the bottom and give me your answers^^

Comment: I have followed your code, but instead errors appear on the page

Comment: On your first post, you call it `this is my code option box`. Do you have an HTML tag like that? `<form method="post" action="">`?

Comment: check my new post eiji and tell me which one is wrong: D

Comment: I have update my html... Sorry i was thinking that you have a form englobing your all html...

Comment: You should add `GetSiswa(  $dep = FALSE )` instead of `GetSiswa()` to your model

Comment: check my latest post, this would work Eiji, see what is wrong ?, only datatables can not display data from the database
oh yes, i'm using plonknimbuzz code

Comment: thanks for you too Eiji, if you do not add your comment then my post will disappear in the swallow earth :D, Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to be helpfull. Actually, my solution isn't really different than plonknimbuzz's one. Good luck with your project.

Comment: hahahaha, yes you're right, it's just that I'm too stupid and can not understand what you're saying

Comment: hei @Eiji can you check my latest question, about checkbox and modal bootstrap, please help me to figure it out